# Sorted function in python writing to a file

Tags: python

The task:

> Your program should read from the file, storing the names and
>   corresponding email addresses in a dictionary as key-value pairs.
>   Then, the program should display a menu that lets the user enter the
>   numbers 1 through 5, each corresponding to a different menu item: 
>   When the user enters 5, the program should write the names and email
>   addresses in alphabetical order by first name to the file
>   phonebook.out You can use the `sorted()` function which accepts a
>   dictionary argument to sort a dictionary based on Key

This is my code:

```
def write_to_file(contact):
    file = open("phonebook.out", "w")
    contactsort = dict(sorted(contact.items()))
    phonebook.write(contact)
    phonebook.close
```

However, this code isn't working. I'm not sure why, so any help is appreciated. thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "isn't working"?, do you get an error?,

Comment: no it doesn't show any error.

Comment: Why do you define `file = ...` but then use `phonebook` to write out your data?

Comment: So should it be file.write? When I change phonebook to file, it highlights file and says invalid syntax.

Comment: It should be the file object where you're trying to store your data. In your code `phonebook` isn't declared anywhere, so I don't know where it comes from and what it means. Anyway, use `with open('phonebook.out', 'w') as file` and then `file.write(...)` for working with files. Check [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried json file?
Like this:

```
import json
filename = "phonebook.json"
def write_to_file(contact):
    with open(filename, 'w') as f_obj:
        contactsort = dict(sorted(contact.items()))
        json.dump(contact, f_obj)
```

Comment: And can you tell what is `contactsort`??

Answer (score 0):

This is your code:

```
def write_to_file(contact):
    file = open("phonebook.out", "w")
    contactsort = dict(sorted(contact.items()))
    phonebook.write(contact)
    phonebook.close
```

As @Cheche mentioned, you are declaring the output as `file` but using it as `phonebook`. Simply replace `file = open("phonebook.out", "w")` with `phonebook = open("phonebook.out", "w")`. Also, you are storing the sorted names to `contactsort` but writing `contact` to the file. As a side note, `phonebook.close` needs to be be `phonebook.close()` with the parentheses to call the function.

The way you sort the `dict` is incorrect. Try:

```
contactsort = {key: contact[key] for key in sorted(contact.iterkeys())}
```

Also, you should try to use `with` when possible. `with` takes care of closing the file for you. Final code:

```
def write_to_file(contact):
    with open("phonebook.out", "w") as phonebook:
        contactsort = {key: contact[key] for key in sorted(contact.iterkeys())}
        phonebook.write(str(contactsort))
```

Answer (score -2):

```
def write_to_file(contact):
    phonebook = open("phonebook.out", "w")
    contactsort = dict(sorted(contact.items()))
    phonebook.write(str(contactsort))
    phonebook.close()    
write_to_file({"name":9090909090, "name_a":8080808080})
```

here You go

Comment: that did not produce an output file

Comment: OP never asked for a pickle, they want plaintext output.

Comment: for text output just use    f.write(str(dict))